# FIreStore Rules - security rule for collection with 2 parameter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection `mobile_user_ranches`

[image: mobile_user_ranches]

I want to add the read rule for this
with respect to the field  `active_user_id` and `company_id`

`active_user_id` is the same as `uid`

How can I pass the company id and set the read rule for this

Comment: That's a tad unclear. Do you mean you only want to allow the current user to read documents within the mobile_user_ranches where active_user_id = auth.uid? (the current users uid). If so, you should *really* take a look at the documentation on [Firestore Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) noting the second example down *another common pattern is to make sure users can only read and write their own data:*